# AWK, Perl or Shell? Unique strings and their maximum values from 3 column data file

Tags: string, perl, shell, awk, unique

I have a file containing data like so:

```
2012-01-02 GREEN 4
2012-01-02 GREEN 6
2012-01-02 GREEN 7
2012-01-02 BLUE 4
2012-01-02 BLUE 3
2012-01-02 GREEN 4
2012-01-02 RED 4
2012-01-02 RED 8
2012-01-02 GREEN 4
2012-01-02 YELLOW 5
2012-01-02 YELLOW 2
```

I can't always predict what the strings are going to be in the second column (so in the example above there are colours but the data file could contain any string in column two). There is always however a number in the third column (which I want the max value of for a paticular string in column two). Is awk able to:

1. Pull out each of the unique strings in column 2?
2. For each of the unique strings get the maximum associated value (so using the above you'd end up with the following)?:

   ```
   2012-01-02 GREEN 7
   2012-01-02 BLUE 4
   2012-01-02 RED 8
   2012-01-02 YELLOW 5
   ```

or would this be easier with Perl (or even shell)? any code examples much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$ sort -k2,2 -k3,3nr input.txt | awk 'x!=$2{x=$2;print}'
2012-01-02 BLUE 4
2012-01-02 GREEN 7
2012-01-02 RED 8
2012-01-02 YELLOW 5
```

Comment: Thanks kev, much appreciated - could you explain what the awk is doing after the pipe?

Comment: @4rd2 `awk` select first line of every group(group by column 2).

Comment: +1, but you don't need sort. awk can do it, albeit a bit more verbosely

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in `perl` or `awk` with pretty much the same technique (using associative arrays).

Here's an `awk` example. `max` contains the (current) maximum for a given "key", `lines` the line that that max happened on.

```
max[$2] < $3 {
  max[$2] = $3
  lines[$2] = $0
}
END {
  for (x in lines)
    print lines[x]
}
```

Comment: +1. You can write the first block a bit more concisely by putting the if-condition outside the block: `max[$2] < $3 {max[$2] = $3; lines[$2] = $0}`

Comment: Neat! Hadn't thought about writing it like that at all, thanks.

Comment: Both forms are valid, but this is less C-like, more awk-like.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
cat -n file | sort -ruk2 | sort -uk2,3 | sort -n | cut -f2
2012-01-02 GREEN 7
2012-01-02 BLUE 4
2012-01-02 RED 8
2012-01-02 YELLOW 5
```

if order is not an issue:

```
sort -k1,2 -k3nr file | sort -uk1,2 
2012-01-02 BLUE 4
2012-01-02 GREEN 7
2012-01-02 RED 8
2012-01-02 YELLOW 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Had similar idea using arrays

```
awk '{i=$1" "$2;if($3>c[i]){c[i]=$3}}END{for(a in c){print a,c[a]}}' colors.txt
2012-01-02 RED 8
2012-01-02 YELLOW 5
2012-01-02 GREEN 7
2012-01-02 BLUE 4
```

and a perl one

```
perl -lne '/^(.*)(\d+)$/;$x{$1}=$2 if $2>$x{$1};END{for(sort keys %x){print $_,$x{$_}}}' colors.txt
2012-01-02 BLUE 4
2012-01-02 GREEN 7
2012-01-02 RED 8
2012-01-02 YELLOW 5
```